# Do exceptions/errors set error number as well in C++?

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling, fstream

In C++, if I have to know, what was the error number/ error for `fstream` opening error; how can I know it. Consider, `fstream` throws the exceptions also by using:

```
file.exceptions ( std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit );
```

In other words, is it necessary that all exceptions set error number also?

Comment: GetLastError may help you

Comment: What is an "error number"? Who told you that fstreams have "error numbers"?

Comment: @KerrekSB Looks like they [do have something like that](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/io_errc).

Comment: @KerrekSB that is what my question is. Does C++ standard defines error numbers/codes for fstreams?

Comment: @jrok: Nice, looks that exists now -- good find! (I was loosely aware of `std::error_code`, but thought it was only used in concurrency stuff.) Yash: Start at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/failure then and see what's available?

Answer (score 0):

*Warning: everything that follows is implementation specific and non portable!*

With my implementation, on Linux at least, C++ iostreams seem to be a wrapper around the lower-level C functions in `stdio.h`. So -- again, on my implementation -- it's possible to get read the `errno` value after something goes wrong with a `std::fstream`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cerrno>

std::ifstream f{filename};
std::string line;
while (f >> line) {
    // Do something with line 
}
if (f.rdstate() == std::ios_base::badbit) {
    int e = errno; // Find the Posix error number
}
```

One more warning: this is not portable, and might not work for you. Did I mention that?